# Published a website, but now my data won't transfer to MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I made a very simple website that asks the user for their name and email, and then it takes those inputs and send them to a table in MySQL. I tested it offline in xampp it worked perfectly fine. So I went and I published it online (I was planning to use github, but I don't think github allows php, so I had to abandon that). I'm using infinity free (or vista panel, the site is kind of confusing). The initial page which has the form on it loads fine, but when the user submits their inputs, it redicts them to a page which reads "ERROR: Could not connect. No such file or directory".

The html code is as follows (index.html):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta content='IE=edge' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' name='viewport'>
    <title>Mongolia to the Moon</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcomponentsjs/0.7.13/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
<div id="title">
<center><h1>Official Petition to Relocate Mongolia to the Moon</h1><center>
</div>

<center><h3>In our eyes, Mongolia is insignificant, and therefore should
 be removed. However, it would be inhumane to destroy innocent lives, even
 for our organization. So we have come to a secondary solution that 
 Mongolia must be transferred elsewhere. The closest place away from earth 
 would be the moon. Please sign the petition below to remove Mongolia from 
 the earth and transfer it to the moon.
</h3><center>

<form action="connect.php" method="post"> 
<table width="20%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="1"> 
<tr> 
  <td>Name:</td> 
  <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="name"></td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
  <td>Email:</td> 
  <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="email"></td> 
</tr>  
<tr> 
  <td>&nbsp;</td> 
  <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td> 
</tr> 
</table> 
</form> 

</body> 
</html>
```

And here is my php (connect.php):

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mypet");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Prepare an insert statement
$sql = "INSERT INTO user (name,email) VALUES (?,?)";

if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
// Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $name,$email);

// Set parameters
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];

// Attempt to execute the prepared statement
if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
    echo "<center><h1>Official Petition to Relocate Mongolia to the 
Moon</h1><center>";
    echo "<center><h3>In our eyes, Mongolia is insignificant, and therefore 
should be removed. However, it would be 
inhumane to destroy innocent lives, even for our organization. So we have 
come to a secondary solution that 
Mongolia must be transferred elsewhere. The closest place away from earth 
would be the moon. Please sign the 
petition below to remove Mongolia from the earth and transfer it to the 
moon.</h3><center>";
    echo "<center><h2>Thank You for Signing the Petition</h2></center>";
} else{
    echo "<center><h1>Official Petition to Relocate Mongolia to the 
Moon</h1><center>";
    echo "<center><h3>In our eyes, Mongolia is insignificant, and therefore 
should be removed. However, it would be 
inhumane to destroy innocent lives, even for our organization. So we have 
come to a secondary solution that 
Mongolia must be transferred elsewhere. The closest place away from earth 
would be the moon. Please sign the 
petition below to remove Mongolia from the earth and transfer it to the 
moon.</h3><center>";
    echo "<center><h2>Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again.</h2>
</center>";
    }
} 

// Close statement
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

This is my first attempt at making a website and coding in html and php and the only language I have experience in is pascal, which isn't really helpful in this with making websites, as far as I know. None of the ideas mentioned in my heading tags should be taken seriously. Just thought I would put that out there in case someone took my (bad) joke the wrong way. Thanks.

Also, if you for some reason need to see the website the link is http://mongolia-pet.rf.gd

Comment: "localhost" probably isn't the location of your database

Comment: @abney317 Do you know how I would go about figuring out what the location is then?

Comment: Start with your hoster's documentation & FAQ ...?

Comment: Possibly relevant: "The MySQL server supports the use of different transport layers for connections. Connections use TCP/IP, Unix domain sockets or Windows named pipes. The hostname *localhost* has a special meaning. It is bound to the use of Unix domain sockets. It is not possible to open a TCP/IP connection using the hostname *localhost* you must use *127.0.0.1* instead." -- [Connections @ PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mypet");
```

The first parameter of mysqli_connect() expects the host name or an IP address, and you provided "localhost" which likely worked in your test environment, however when you published the site you that removed connection locally.

Most likely you're MySQL didn't get moved onto the live server. In this case you need to either:

- provide the external IP address of the server the MySQL database resides on instead of "localhost".
- move the MySQL onto the same server as the site

Hope this helps!